# How to disable default web middleware in Laravel5.2?

Tags: laravel-5

I have a server async notify route :

```
Route::post('notify/payment/{gateway}','Payment@receiveNotify')
```

How to disable default web middleware ? (session and verifycsrftoken)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in the `map()` method of your `RouteServiceProvider`.

> Keep in mind, the web middleware group is automatically applied to your default routes.php file by the RouteServiceProvider.

https://www.laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware#middleware-groups

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can Just remove the 'middleware' => 'web' block entirely and continue like you used to.

But I prefer below option.

Go to your app/providers/RouteServiceProvider.php file and update like below and as per you needs:

For e.g :

```
public function map(Router $router)
{
    $this->mapWebRoutes($router);
    $this->mapApiRoutes($router);
}


protected function mapWebRoutes(Router $router)
{
    $router->group([
        'namespace' => $this->namespace, 'middleware' => 'web',
    ], function ($router) {
        require app_path('Http/routes.php');
    });

}


protected function mapApiRoutes(Router $router)
{
     $router->group([
         'namespace' => $this->namespace, 'middleware' => 'api',
     ], function ($router) {
         require app_path('Http/routes-api.php');
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case, since I am using API based development, I just commented out this line in app/Http/Kernel.php

// \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,

Answer (score 0):

Since Laravel 7.7 you can use method `withoutMiddleware` eg:

```php
Route::post('notify/payment/{gateway}','Payment@receiveNotify')->withoutMiddleware(['csrf']);
```